# How to wrap text in label automatically in Tcl/Tk?

Tags: linux, text, label, tcl, tk-toolkit

Has anyone ever done or have any idea how to do an automatic [`label`] line break? Or self-intelligent to recognize that arrived at the end of each line, ie, at the edge of the margin, limited to the widget itself?

## Code:

```
package require Img

# Container
frame .fr -borderwidth 2 -bg white 

# Text Variable
set description "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris"

# Thumbnail
image create photo pic -file /home/tc/webvideo/galinha_pitadinha/seu_lobato.jpg
button .fr.bt -relief flat -bg white -image pic

# Description
label .fr.lb -bg white -textvariable description -wraplength 250 -width 30 -justify left

pack .fr .fr.bt .fr.lb -side left -fill x -padx .5c -pady .5c
```

## Code Result:

[image]

**Programmatically speaking, I intend it to look like this:**

[image]

***I want to break the sentence, as well as the illustrative image above.***

Note that the regular expression is missing to hunt **the end of the second line** and marry the little pots (ellipses) at the end. And of course, hide the rest of the text.

All text will be shown when hovering over the `label` widget via: `tooltip`

I've been thinking of two hypotheses. Are they:

- 1) Shows the total amount of "characters" within Text variable

  `tk_messageBox -message [string length $description]`
- 2) Shows the total amount of "words" within Text variable

  `tk_messageBox -message [llength $description]`

## I stopped here:

> In this setting of the `-wraplength 250` property, I have a variation of *10 words* for every two lines.
>   Based on this, I can apply a condition and put the amount of *word* or *character* as a determining factor to only display up to the second line.

```
# If it were to quantify Characters and not words, this would be
if {[string length $description] < 40} {
pack [label .b -textvariable description -wraplength 250 -width 30 -justify left] -side top -fill x
}
```

Or to compare a certain number of words which in the case here is 10 words. And if true, perform the action of Regular Expression

```
 # If it were to quantify words and not characters, this would be
 if {[llength $description] <10} {
  ... RegExp code here ...
 }
```

Comment: Try seeing if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16513476/1578604) helps?

Comment: @Jerry I just read the topic, it's really what I really needed. I just asked the question because nothing I found related in my web search. The difference was due to not having found the terminology sought. I thought and searched for a different title from the author of the question there. But **is the same intent in part**, ***because some of the details that I covered in framing my question are not seen there***.

Comment: @Jerry For example, limit the amount of characters in the `label` and add the ellipsis in order. Thank you anyway! But I want to keep this issue in the air, because I consider my doubts to be resolved in part. I think I still have a chance to get an answer on how to limit the number of characters in the `label` text at least that I want to know from someone more experienced.

Comment: No problem, it took me a while too to find the question and I only know about it because I remembered it was out there. And sure, your question is still fine, just about half of it resolved. For the remaining part, if you want to limit the number of characters, you can use a similar method to the answers in the linked question, then using an additional regexp like `regexp {.{1,X}} $input output` (where X is the character from which other characters are discarded). I don't know if it's possible to make the text automatically match the frame though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This coding, which I did at dawn seems to me a possible solution. However, I have not yet tested coding allied with the **Tk** *library*. I will do the test, and any news, in case of success or failure. I will update this answer.

What I am basically doing here (in this code below) is to create a file as a pointer from where I will start to find the two lines that I want to show on the label. Follow the comments included in the source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Opening a nonexistent file (empty)
set file [open "input.txt" w]

# Writing on it ..
puts $file "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris"

# Close. This saves a few bytes.
close $file

# Opening it again, now let's read.
set file [open "input.txt" r]

# Read me.
set read [read $file]

# Now I need to replace multiple spaces with '+' as a reference for
# we quantify and subsequently break the phrase into the variable at this point (+)
set add [string map -nocase {{ } {+}} $read]

# Just an index, indicator that starts counting the for loop
set count 0
for {set value 0} {$value<10} {incr value} {

# In this variable I will extract line-by-line
set number [lindex $add $count]

# Now I create a list
set data [list]

# It's time to break the text by the '+' signs, saving the result (a list of words) in the data variable
lappend data [split $number +]

# Just an index, indicator that starts counting the while loop
set indice 0

# Loop running until 10 words are exhausted
while {$indice<10} {

# Is this variable , wich show result
# shows us the words the loop went through until the set value ended: 10
   set result [lindex $data 0 $indice]

    # See them now on screen, detail!
        # The variable phrase, which was once a single line, was broken and passed to the list.
        # Thus, every word followed by its comma (,) and / or period (.)
        # are in a single column, you will need to format them again to be displayed in "a single row"
        # We enter the argument "-nonewline" getting all words extracted by on one line
        # The space purposely placed in front of the variable "$ result"
        # Is required to have space between words again       
          puts -nonewline "$result "
   incr indice
}
        incr count
      puts ".."
   break
}

close $file
```

## Result output:

**PrintScreen**

[image]

It is worth mentioning here, the that I pack have in my machine (micro computer) Are, packages of Tcl 8.4 and 8.5 not have 8.6 yet.  This are my ambient of works programing in Tcl/Tk.

> But I did the code and ran the tests on this online [platform](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php), running Tcl 8.6.

---

My concern and work now was to adapt the code above with the Tk library.

I had the task of capturing the output and retrieving it. All at runtime.

I tried several times to pass the output of the `put` command into another variable that could retrieve the new content.

But unfortunately, i dot not how haver sucess. Because i m new from  language programing Tcl.

So, I made this capture using Shell Script Unix with Script Tcl. See the part(s):

- Here recover output of command `put`:

  `set txt [exec cat ./output.txt]`
- Here put output: *-textvariable `txt`*

  `label .fr.lb -bg white -textvariable txt -wraplength 250 -width 30 -justify left`

Now puts code in wrapper this  `procedure` all terminates a call do the Tcl script process and transfers it to the Bourn Shell script which, in turn, returns a window with the already formatted of `label` text. Like this:

```
proc test {} { 
     .. The code .. 
  put "output some text"
}

# invoke in file end 
test
```

Without further explanation, just analyze and draw conclusions.

Now see the structure

Let's redirect the output of the `puts` command to an external file `output.txt`.

We have to create 3 files, two of them are Tcl and another Bourne Shell. Look:

**test.tcl:** Script Tcl main

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# \
exec wish "$0" "$@"

package require Img

set txt [exec cat ./output.txt]

# Container
frame .fr -borderwidth 2 -bg white 

# Thumbnail
image create photo pic -file thumb.jpg
button .fr.bt -relief flat -bg white -image pic

# Description
label .fr.lb -bg white -textvariable txt -wraplength 250 -width 30 -justify left

# The help texts, as we said, stay in an array:

set subtitle(.fr.lb) [exec cat ./input.txt]

# The frame that will contain the help text itself:

frame .help -bd 1 -bg black
label .help.lab -wraplength 200 -width 30 -text "Texto da subtitle" -bg lightyellow -justify left
pack .help.lab

# Note that we do not materialize the frame as we do not want it to appear now.

# Now comes the most important part. When the mouse cursor enters a button, we should start the process of "Show in the future" the help frame.

bind .fr.lb <Enter> {+
    set subtitle(win) %W
    .help.lab config -text $subtitle(%W)
    set subtitle(id) [after 500 place .help \
        -x [expr %x + [winfo x %W]] \
        -y [expr %y + [winfo y %W] + 20] ]
}

# 

bind .fr.lb <Leave> {+
    if [info exists subtitle(id)] {
        after cancel $subtitle(id)
        unset subtitle(id)
    }
    place forget .help
}

pack .fr .fr.bt .fr.lb -side left -fill x -padx .5c -pady .5c
```

**test.sh:** Invoke script test.tcl e transfer the output of command put

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" "$@"

set file [open "input.txt" w]

puts $file "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris"

close $file

proc test {} {

set file [open "input.txt" r]

set read [read $file]

set add [string map -nocase {{ } {+}} $read]

set value 0

for {set value 0} {$value<10} {incr value} {

set number [lindex $add $value]

set data [list]

lappend data [split $number +] 

set indice 0

while {$indice<10} {
    set result [lindex $data 0 $indice]
    puts -nonewline "$result "
    incr indice
    }    
  incr value
  puts ".."
  break
  }
 close $file
}

# Invoke
test
```

**main.tcl:** Insert the out of command put in file output.txt

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" "$@"

exec ./test.sh > ./output.txt 
exec ./test.tcl
```

I didn't want code to be in separate files, but this was well organized.

> When using the code with the Tk library, the adaptation has been in parallel development .. which remains in the same way: That, being on the same plane, do not cut each other.

*I will leave the scripts as well as the picture to download with from my Google Drive Account - [Acess to get](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1z0mhRYeh4dNbCTcKuhhy8uYFI-uz01JS?usp=sharing)!*

The response code has been too long because it includes the `tooltip` code along with.

## Printscreen:

[image]

If i upgrade code now, or later, i post the changes. Thanks the All, by contributions

Answer (score 2):

The *label* widget takes a [`-wraplength` option](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/options.htm#M-wraplength). It takes a wrapping width to apply in any of the forms for providing a screen distance measure (e.g., `190` of 190 pixels, `5c` for 5 centimetres).

The (rarely used) *message* widget can instead focus on trying to attain a particular aspect ratio for the text it contains.

---

You can do ellipsis injection in your script provided you are willing to destructively change the text being displayed.

```
pack [label .l -textvar msg]
set msg "Lorem ipsum,\nfoo bar grill whatever to make this long"

proc trimWithEllipsis {msg width font {ellipsis ...}} {
    set ew [font measure $font $ellipsis]
    set out ""
    foreach c [split $msg ""] {
        if {[font measure $font $out$c] > $width} {
            set oute ""
            foreach c2 [split $out ""] {
                if {[font measure $font $oute$c2$ellipsis] > $width} {
                    return $oute$ellipsis
                }
                append oute $c2
            }
            # failed to find ellipsis injection point??? keep going normally... 
        }
        append out $c
    }
    return $msg
}

# How to apply the code
set msgLines {}
foreach line [split $msg "\n"] {
    # 200 (pixels) was a good demonstration value on this system
    lappend msgLines [trimWithEllipsis $line 200 [.l cget -font]]
}
set msg [join $msgLines "\n"]
```

I've had a word with other Tk developers, and we're agreed that this sort of thing ought to be a core feature, especially as it would also apply to other widget types nicely too (especially entries and listboxes). Another reason that this ought to be a core feature is that it would mean that the details of wrapping wouldn't be part of the Model (i.e., the contents of the variable/`-message` property) but rather be purely a View concern. But there's no chance of it making 8.6 or before.

Comment: Automatic insertion of ellipses isn't a feature of Tk at this point. You might wish to do a Feature Request over at core.tcl.tk...

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, but I tried to execute your response code a few times, and couldn't find a way on how to implement it, in this excerpt: `Error in startup script: invalid command name" lmap "`. It seems to me that this event is new, does not run Tcl 8.4 or 8.5

Comment: Ah, yes. It's an 8.6 feature. I'll rewrite for older Tcl.

Comment: Also, the code will not do well in the case where the wrap width is shorter than the width of the ellipsis. Unsurprisingly...